# AngularJS form returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm writing a simple login service, I'm just trying to make username and password, send them to php and get simple console.log 'GJ'. Everything works fine until i get response 'Error' from my PHP function. I tryed to console.log data I'm sending and it says undefined. I tryed to stringify with JSON same thing. Can anyone check where i have it wrong

**HTML**

```
       <div class="container login">
       <div class="column column-4">
        <form  name="from1" role="form">

        <label for="">{{user.mail}}</label> <br>
        <input type="text"  placeholder="username" required ng-   
         model="user.mail"><br>
        <label for="">{{user.pass}}</label> <br>
        <input type="text"  placeholder="password" required ng-
        model="user.pass"><br>
        <button  name="submit" class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="login()">   
         Submit</button>
         </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**MAIN.JS**

```
    app.factory('loginService',function($http){
    return{
        login:function(user,scope){
            var $promise = $http.post('http://site1.local/user.php', user);   
       //send data to user.php
            $promise.then(function(msg){
                if(msg.data=='success') console.log("GJ");
                else console.log("DARN IT");
            });
        }
     }

});

app.controller('LoginCtrl', function( $scope, loginService ) {
   $scope.login=function(user){
      console.log(user);
        loginService.login(user,$scope); //call login service
    };
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $user = json_decode($data);
    if($user->mail=='admin' && $user->pass=='1234') 
        print 'success';
    else 
        print 'error';

?>
```

Comment: If you inspect 'msg' in the $promise.then function, what do you see?

Comment: i consle.log(msg) and i get 

undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the user in your ng-click function

```js
ng-click = "login(user)"
```

Comment: Ye now console logs correctly but i still get error as print return.

Comment: Finaly i got it. Thanks mate a lot